# WSDL file format keywords?

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap

I have wsdl file, Please let me know how to find these NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, ACTION_METHOD & SOAP_URL from wsdl?

Below is my wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.helloworld.com">
<wsdl:types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.helloworld.com">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="../../xsd/csr_loginonPswd.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="TVSignonPswdRq">
<wsdl:part name="IFXRq" element="impl:IFXRq"/></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="TVSignonPswdRs"><wsdl:part name="IFXRs" 
element="impl:IFXRs"/></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType 
name="TVSignonPswdPortType"><wsdl:operation 
name="TVSignonPswdOperation"><wsdl:input 
message="impl:TVSignonPswdRq"/><wsdl:output 
message="impl:TVSignonPswdRs"/></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="TVSignonPswdBinding" 
type="impl:TVSignonPswdPortType"><soap:binding style="document" 
transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation 
name="TVSignonPswdOperation"><soap:operation 
soapAction="http://www.popularinc.com/" style="document"/><wsdl:input>
<soap:body parts="IFXRq" use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output>
<soap:body parts="IFXRs" use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="TVSignonPswd">
<wsdl:port name="TVSignonPswdPort" binding="impl:TVSignonPswdBinding">
<soap:address location="http://00.000.000.000:0000"/></wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

Can we find above mentioned URL's from given WSDL? Or I need another file format?

Comment: Programmatically or by looking at it? You might want to format your wsdl properly. One long line is very bad.

Comment: No But my question is can we find these 4 format from given WSDL?

Comment: Yes or no is not an appropriate response to an *X or Y* question.